# How to dynamically change the style of a comma separated tags with html/css/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I want to achieve works exactly like the tag section of this website when try to make a question entry. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: You could use a jquery plugin, for example: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

Comment: @OllyHodgson http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be using the Tag-It jQuery Plugin (http://webspirited.com/tagit/docs.html). It is very easy to use, understand and implement.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, looking into it immediately.

Comment: Worked just fine, you rock.